# How to POST with AngularJS to WebApi .NET/C# controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, http, post, asp.net-web-api2

I know there are similar questions like mine around, but I couldn't find a solution, so here I am.
Here's my AngularJS staff:

```
$scope.someData = {
    Name: "Bob",
    PhoneNo: 123
};

var data = {
    SomeData: $scope.somedata
};

var response = $http({
    url: "/api/BlaBla/BlaBlaMethod",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
});
return response;
```

Here's the C# controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string BlaBlaMethod(MyModel myModel)
{
    // do something
}
```

And the Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public SomeData SomeData { get; set; }
}

public class SomeData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

I tried with `public string BlaBlaMethod([FromBody]MyModel myModel)`,
`public List<SomeData> SomeData { get; set; }`,
`dataType: 'json', data: JSON.stringify(data)`
and some other tries with the angularjs $http service, but *myModel.Data* won't fill.
Please, help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this with model object defined in angular js, and receive it in your api controller.

```
$scope.SomeData= {
'Name': value,
'PhoneNo': value
}

$http.post('/api/BlaBla/BlaBlaMethod',  { SomeData : $scope.SomeData}).then(
    function(){
       // function if successfully returned from webapi.
     }, 
    function(){
       // function if error returned from webapi.
     }
);
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `$http({
    url: "/api/BlaBla/BlaBlaMethod",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
 JSON.stringify(data)
});` ??

Comment: yes it is, this looks little clean, but even in your sequence you will need to define callbacks for success and error. check here for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I have callbacks already defined, I didn't put them in the question as they are irrelevant. The problem is with the controller not accepting the data...

Comment: I have edited answer, try that and let me know if that resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't want to post `SomeData : $scope.SomeData`, but I want to post `data` which among other things includes `SomeData : $scope.SomeData`. Can't apply your answer for my needs.